# Will Wordpress updates overwrite code I customised?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I use a Wordpress theme that I have customised a lot.
If I update Wordpress or the theme that I'm using, will it overwrite the code I customised in the theme or Wordpress system?
Or can I just update everything.

Same with Wordpress plug-ins: I've written some extra code in the Woocommerce's cart script. If I update WooCommerce, will it be lost or overwritten?

Comment: Short Answer: Yes, your customization's will be overwritten when updating, that's why child-themes should be used and editing core files should be avoided...

Comment: You can update the WordPress version without any problem. The theme will not be affected. Updating the theme on the other hand will cause you to lose your changes. Regarding the plugins, you will also lose the changes. Always try using plugin's own filters / actions instead of modifying the plugin code directly.

Comment: What @user8230352 says is technically correct, but its not always possible to *only* update Wordpress - some themes and plugins may not work with the latest version of Wordpress and therefore you may be required to update them to work. So it's possible you may need to update your customised files as a knock-on effect of updating WP only.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you update the plugins and themes, those will be overwritten and you will lose the changes you made.

Comment: How can you prevent that it will be lost? Because I need to update.

Comment: you create child theme and you copy every file you need to edit in child theme and edit that file